# build screenrecord for android 4.2

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source, android-mediacodec

Is it possible to build screenrecord binary to run on 4.2 , or are there too many missing apis ?
Can I workaround changed apis and libraries ? because as far as I understand  the main parts exist in 4.2 ( like mediacodec ) . I dont need the muxer I can use my own muxing for 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be difficult.

`screenrecord` shipped in Android 4.4, but except for one minor API (to tear down the virtual display) everything it needs is present in Android 4.3.

Android 4.2 lacks some important things.  The `MediaMuxer` class didn't exist, and `MediaCodec` didn't yet have the `createInputSurface()` call.  As you noted it's not hard to work around the former, but for the latter you either have to feed `MediaCodec` raw YUV buffers (which is difficult to do pre-4.3, and will reduce your frame rate), or (since `screenrecord` is using private internal APIs already) interface directly with libstagefright to implement your own "metadata mode" handling.

I'm not sure offhand what the state of virtual displays was in 4.2, but you'd also need those to work fully.

Companies like [Kamcord](https://www.kamcord.com/) and [Everyplay](https://everyplay.com/) advertise that they can do game recording back to Android 4.1, but I suspect they're recording the OpenGL ES rendering (rather than virtual display output) and doing a lot of internal plumbing themselves.

Comment: is there a way to get screen frames as somthing smaller than raw YUV ? maybe jpeg or png ?

Comment: doesnt miracast manage to do fast screen capture from gpu in 4.2?

Comment: fadden, is there an irc channel on we can discuss screenrecord related issues ?

Comment: You can't get smaller than YUV from the compositor, so you'd have to compress it yourself, which takes too long.  Miracast streaming in 4.2 is an example of using libstagefright directly; see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/kitkat-release/media/libstagefright/SurfaceMediaSource.cpp (which was the starting point for GraphicBufferSource.cpp, which implements MediaCodec Surface input).  Don't know about IRC channels, but there are a number of blog posts from people who have dug into stagefright and SurfaceMediaSource.